# inputting an array in a SOAP request

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have a SOAP request that I generated from SOAP UI and see how to specify strings and ints, but I'm not sure how to input the array for the testAddress field. Here's the wsdl and below is the soap request. Any idea how I say either one email address or two. tim@tim.com and tom@tim.com. Thanks!

http://api.stormpost.datranmedia.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor?wsdl

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.web.stormpost.skylist.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <authInfo xsi:type="soap:authentication" xmlns:soap="http://skylist.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor">
         <!--You may enter the following 2 items in any order-->
         <username xsi:type="xsd:string">username</username>
         <password xsi:type="xsd:string">password</password>
      </authInfo>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:sendTestMessage soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <mailingID xsi:type="xsd:int">#trim(mailingID)#</mailingID>
         <testAddresses xsi:type="soap:ArrayOf_soapenc_string" soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[]" xmlns:soap="http://skylist.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
         <part xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">html</part>
      </ser:sendTestMessage>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ser:sendTestMessage soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <cfoutput> <mailingID xsi:type="xsd:int">#trim(mailingID)#</mailingID></cfoutput>
         <testAddresses xsi:type="soap:ArrayOf_soapenc_string" soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[1]" xmlns:soap="http://skylist.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <testAddresses xsi:type="xsd:string">tim@tim.com</testAddresses>
        </testAddresses>
         <part xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">HTML</part>
      </ser:sendTestMessage>
```